# How to send an email with user email, in contact us page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I am creating a contact us page, and i want to receive mails from this page as its a mail came from the user mail.

I wrote this code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "password"),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("userEmail@any.com");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com"));
                mail.Body = "bodyTest";
                mail.Subject = "subjectTest";
                client.Send(mail);
```

But i receive the mail from my mail not the user

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tested with an other smptserver/provider?

Comment: no, because i want it work with gmail, i tested in past and it was working with different server, seams for me the problem in gmail.

Comment: Its a security feature of gmail so that one account can't send email mascaraing as other accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using gmail, the message will come from the user logging in, not the user in the "from". You can put whatever you'd like in the from, but it doesn't work the way you'd expect.

Using a small, free Google Apps account, I've actually set up a 'bot@example.com' account. I log into gmail with that account, so at least contact mail has that as the from.

Comment: The answer above is correct for GMail, if you were using for example Exchange Server you could change the from address to noreply@foobar.com but for GMail it takes your credentials login as the from email address.

Comment: Can you expand more on the workaround? I just implemented a contact-us page and I find it annoying that that I can't receive emails as if it would have been sent from the actual sender. Our mail-server is Google Apps Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue, and there is kinda workaround for this, you can add the sender's email to the [`ReplyToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist.aspx) property, which will give the option to reply to that address.