# How to put contact us page in windows application c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to send an email programmatically without using any actual email account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747065/is-it-possible-to-send-an-email-programmatically-without-using-any-actual-email)

I want to put a contact me page in my windows application. I'm very new to all this I have got this to work [How to send an email with user email, in contact us page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047916/how-to-send-an-email-with-user-email-in-contact-us-page) But it is not sufficient the main reason being is I know people that use my application would be able to get the password from the .exe file if they really wanted to. Is there any other option?

Comment: I'd use a relay smtp that doesn't require a password, if I were you.

Comment: Thanks Wimbo, But im not to sure there would be one of those out there. OR everyone would be using it for spamming others. I could and probably be very wrong. Isnt there some sort of of way to create some sort of http post that will fill in the subject message body etc? so my desktop app will call that webpage on my site and supply the data (body, subject) on the URL or as a POST?

Comment: I dont have this problem because I have my own servers and can configure whatever I need to server-side. I assume you are limited by the fact you dont have your own servers to play with?

Comment: Burkhan Khalid its not a duplicate. Because that response never actually answered the problem correctly. You would still be forced to put a password in your code for the smtp server caesay i do have a windows server but im very new to all this i have been programming in php for a long time c# maybe a month.

Comment: Im thinking the way may to have my application create a link like domainnamegoeshere.com/mymessage.php?=subject=mysubject etc etc So the app would be basically filling out an invisible form on my site is that possible?

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of asp.net web services but yes, this would work.

Comment: wimbo, yea this is the first software application i have ever written. I know php pretty well so my site is written in it. This is all new to me i appreciate you helping and being patient with me. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like they closed my question. Because supposedly its an"exact duplicate" You ever think the answers that were given in that supposed "exact duplicate" was not feasible? Anyone know another website were nazis don't take down your questions? Or they don't edit you being friendly out of your question like thanks for reading thanks for the help..Seriously this site is a joke.